# Identifying a set $S$ with a subset in $T$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S = \{1,2\} \subset \mathbb{N}$, and $T = \{5,6,7\} \subset \mathbb{N}$. Clearly, $S \not\subset T$.

Let $i:S \to \{5,6\}$ be such that $i(n) = n+4$. This is injective and surjective. So, $i$ is an isomorphism.

Then, can I "identify" $S$ with a subset of $T$ via $i$, and hence $S \subset T$? If yes, what is the mathematical machinary behind this? Are we using the equivalence relation "$n \sim i(n)$ for $n \in S$"?

Comment: But what are you trying to prove ? That $S \subset T$ ? This can be shown simply using the def of $\subset$ : $S \subset T$ iff for all $x$, if $x \in S$, then $x \in T$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA - I am trying to understand the math behind the concept of "identifying" elements of two sets. For example, the real number $r \in \mathbb{R}$ are "identified" with $(r,0) \in \mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}^2$, and the real numbers are considered to be a subset of the complex this way. But technically, they are not, if you see complex numbers as ordered pairs.

Comment: Ok, thanks: now I understand. But the isomorphism is not an equivalence relation. If you use your example, $\mathbb R$ is not a subset of $\mathbb C$; the set $\{ (r,0) : r \in \mathbb R \}$ **is** a subset of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA - That is what I thought. "Officially", the reals are isomorphic to a subfield of the complex, and not technically a subset in my example. Another example is a free module $F(S)$ with basis $S$. The set $S$ need not be in $F(S)$ but authors (e.g. Dummit and Foote) often "identify" elements in $S$ with $i(S)$, where $i:S \to F(S)$ is the injection used in the universal property. Then they will say $S \subset F(S)$. Is this the same as what I have done with $S$ and $T$ in my question?

Comment: Yes; we have $i(S) \subset F(S)$; but being *isomorphic*, we "identify" $S$ and $i(S)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no actual mathematics behind this type of convention.

Any suppressed identification (such as $\Bbb R \subseteq \Bbb C$ as in the comments) is an *abuse of notation*, which aids our intuition because we can guess (or "intuitively know", if you prefer) what the identification/inclusion map $i: \Bbb R \hookrightarrow \Bbb C$ is.

This kind of "abuse" makes our life easier because it allows us to obfuscate trivialities and focus on the interesting stuff at hand.

For example, if $F' \subseteq F$ is a subfield, then we will usually use $+$ for both addition in $F'$ and in $F$. But then if we write $f_1 + f_2$ for $f_1,f_2 \in F'$, do we mean $+: F' \times F' \to F'$ or $+: F \times F \to F$? Obviously, it "doesn't matter", so we drop the distinction.

---

If you are interested in this kind of thing, consider having a look at category theory. Through making this type of identification explicit, it uncovers a lot of interesting results applicable in all of mathematics. Have a look at the concept of a "forgetful functor".